# Writing in the hole of a memory-mapped sparse file

Tags: linux, file-io, filesystems, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

I need to have a file where certain bytes are contiguously laid out. Lets call these chunks. The reason the chunks need to be laid out contiguously is that these eventually get memory-mapped to an array. A file would have several chunks(these correspond to different but related arrays), and these chunks need to be appended over time. The first thing I thought about is to use a sparse file and have holes at the inter-chunk boundaries.

Whenever I have new data I could then write in the hole. If the space available in the hole is not enough I intend to move minimum amount of bytes to create the space and (some extra space for future) and then write the data.

1. Is this a wrong way to do things ?
2. Are there good alternatives to this approach
3. How does the OS (Linux) handle a write in the hole, does it
   move(shift) all the bytes in the tail ? Or restructures the inodes to somehow accommodate (at the cost of fragmentation)
4. Is there an optimal way to do this so that amortized movement cost is
   small

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Most likely, yes.
2. Linux already comes with a system for tracking multiple, contiguous byte sequences with efficient appends: the file system. Can't you just use multiple files?
3. If you use a modern Linux fs (i.e. not FAT32), it'll leave the existing data in place and allocate additional space. This could be either in a pre-allocated extent/block or by fragmentation. It's left to the FS to figure that out.
4. "Optimal" depends on your usage patterns and how much you value time vs space. It's hard to make general comments, but there are many CS papers on how to allocate and reallocate chunks of bytes given various assumptions.

Comment: Thanks upvoted. Re 2. I have considered it. It worries me that there are way too many of these chunks (10K say), and  each chunk is small (could be <1K). Reiser4 I think would have been ideal, but sadly its not in the mainline. Do you have suggestions for a suitable filesystem

Comment: Any file system will easily handle 10k small files. ext4 is a good default.

Comment: I see. I thought the min default blocksize for ext4 is 4K or more and it does not reuse the empty space in the blocks.

Comment: When you start approaching a million chunks, consider using smaller blocks (`mkfs.ext4 -b`) and larger inodes (`-I`).